# authenticated referral not working but oauth url works

Tags: authentication, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

I have two methods of authenticating users.  One is the normal oauth way from my website:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=161077997258367&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.shopography.com%2F&scope=email%2Coffline_access%2Cuser_birthday%2Cpublish_actions%2Cpublish_stream%2Cread_stream%2Cstatus_update&state=%7B%22rID%22%3A570001%7D

This returns a code which I can then use to request an auth_token.  No problems there!

However, when I click on a link internal to Facebook which is configured for authenticated referral, I get a code that Facebook rejects and therefore, I get no auth_token.

The error I get with authenticated referall is:
{"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException"}}

Any ideas?

Comment: i've further learned that authenticated referral works but only on my base domain such as www.example.com.  the minute i do something like www.example.com/hello/ or www.example/?state=hello then the code no longer works

Answer (score 1):

Get the current URL from the authenticated referral request and use it up to the '&code=..'. as redirect_uri when exchanging access token.